# Nested Dictionary rearrange keys assigned numerically

Tags: python, dictionary, key

So I created a dictionary with keys as number, having multiple values for each key.

I need to follow this criteria when deleting a key.

"3. Delete Contact

a. Prompt the user to enter the entry number to be deleted.

b. After deleting a record, all succeeding entries will move forward."

Is there a way to rearrange the numbers on the dictionary keys. Because whenever I delete a key it leaves a number open. Example : I have key 1-5, I del 3 I am left with 1,2,4,5

Comment: The whole idea of a dictionary is to have keys mapped to values. Changing this mapping with every deletion of an entry is very much opposing this idea. Use lists and use `enumerate` when displaying the list to the user.

Comment: I need to create an address book tho, so I used dictionary to assign 4 values(firstname,lastname,contactnumber,address) to multiple keys(numerical order)